# How to get the current user when updating a gridview in an asp.net c# web forms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-membership

I have as asp.net c# web forms application in which I have a gridview.  I need to update the `doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by` field with the current user when updating.  Here is the update command in the sql data source for the gridview:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_doc_rvw_sub] 
                    SET [doc_rvw_sub_status_list] = @doc_rvw_sub_status_list,
                        [doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by] = ,
                        [doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set] = GetDate()
                    WHERE   [doc_rvw_sub_id_pk] = @original_doc_rvw_sub_id_pk"
```

Here are the update parameters in the sql data source:

```
<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_doc_rvw_sub_status_list" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set" Type="DateTime" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

I'm not sure how to get the value for `System.Web.HttpContext.Identity.Name` into the `doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by field`.  Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Pass it using the asp.net special tags like `<%: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>`

Comment: I tried adding the special tag to the update command but I get an error stating that I have incorrect syntax near <.

Comment: easiest to do in code behind  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863802/how-to-use-user-identity-name-as-a-parameter-for-sqldatasource-in-asp-net